# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a problem with a WPF APP.

[image: WPF APP]

When I press the up button (nach oben) or down button (nach unten) and there is no item in the list inserted, it should not give me the error: `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. (Parameter 'index')'`

When I already inserted some items, the up and down button works as intended.

There error is shown on `private void Verschieben -> listBox.Items.Insert(index,item);`

```
namespace Lektion1Neu
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Verschieben(int index)
        {
            Object item = listBox.SelectedItem;
            listBox.Items.Remove(item);
            listBox.Items.Insert(index,item);
            listBox.SelectedIndex = index;
        }

        private void beenden_Click(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void uebernehmen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(textBox.Text);
            statusLabel.Content = "Eintrag übernommen";
        }

        private void btnNachOben_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox.SelectedIndex;
            if (index == 0)
                index = listBox.Items.Count -1;
            else
                index--;
            Verschieben(index);
            statusLabel.Content = "Eintrag nach oben verschoben";
                
        }
        private void btnNachUnten_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox.SelectedIndex;
            if (index == listBox.Items.Count -1)
                index = 0;
            else
                index++;
            Verschieben(index);
            statusLabel.Content = "Eintrag nach unten verschoben";
        }


        private void btnLöschen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /*int index = listBox.SelectedIndex;
            listBox.Items.RemoveAt(index);
            */
            while(listBox.SelectedItems.Count >0)
                listBox.Items.Remove(listBox.SelectedItems[0]);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You presumably just want to do nothing if the button is pressed and there are no items.

Something like:

```
private void btnNachUnten_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox.Items.Count == 0)
    {
       return;
    }
```

But the usual wpf way is ICommand and you'd use canexecute to disable the buttons. That would grey them as well.

Comment: But it also doens't work like this when items are in the list...

Comment: Then there is another problem as well as the one you described and your statement "When I already inserted some items, the up and down button works as intended." Is not true.